# Trigger python script as soon as a specific USB device is attached to the system

Tags: python, usb, pywinusb

I have a python script which has to be executed everytime using command line. What i want to try out is as soon as the windows detects a new USB device has plugged in with a specific vendor id and product id , i want to run the script , basically to automate the process on usb plug in

Comment: Your question is too broad. But I guess you will need either something that checks permanently the usb ports states, or verify if windows has a trigger when something is plugged.

Answer (score 0):

Not the full answer but guess this will help you. I suggest you to use C# to run relevant python script by using a library like [IronPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c). You can use devicechange from [winAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19210421/how-to-obtain-devices-info-from-wm-devicechange) with C# as well.